# Existence of Simple functions converging uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be a function on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Assume that $f$ is measurable and for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $f(x) \in [0,M]$; some $M \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Show there is a sequence of simple functions $f_n$ also taking on values in $[0,M]$ such that

$$f_n \xrightarrow{\text{uniform}} f.$$

My attempt. Take some partition of the interval, and define characteristics on these intervals then you have a sequence of simple functions then apply Egorovs theorem to give us uniform convergence on a closed subset that barely fits in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (by barely fits I mean the measure of the complement is small). Is this a correct approach or? Possibly a nested sequence of subsets of $[0,M]$? I am thinking like $\bigcup_{n=1}^M[0,n]$ but $M$ may not be integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f_n(x)= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{[2^{n}M]+1} \frac {k-1} {2^{n}} \chi_{\frac {k-1} {2^{n}} \leq f(x) <\frac {k} {2^{n}}}$ and verify that $|f_n(x)-f(x)| <\frac 1 {2^{n}}$ for all $x$. This has the additonal property that $f_n$'s **increase** to $f$ uniformly.

Comment: would something more simple work like the idea I had? like for $n<M$ intervals that look like $[0,n]$ but is my major issue in that $M \notin \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame I am taking the integer part of $2^{n}M$ to take care of the fact that $M$ need not be an integer.

Comment: also, what if $($2^nM+1)$\notin \mathbb{Z}$ or did you intend least integer function or the floor function up top

Comment: oh so it is the least integer function you invoke then, correct?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Yes, that is what I did.

Comment: can I apply Egorovs Theorem to just get the uniform continuity? as apposed to proving it using $\epsilon-\delta$?

Comment: When you can directly construct a sequence $(f_n)$ from $f$ why do you wnat to apply any theorem at all?  @HossienSahebjame

Comment: Ok so when you say constructed from $f$, we do not know what $f$ looks like at all, but in its definition would there be a $\chi_{[0,M]}$? can we express it as a simple function itself? Sorry if this is silly question.